# OnClick event on Link component

Tags: reactjs

I have a page with a few `NavLink`s, I need to set the parent's state with the name of the clicked `NavLink`, how can I do that if `NavLink`s doesn't have an OnClick` event?

I would want to do something like that:

```
<Tile to="./request" department={item.catName} key={item.id} 
      onClick={() => this.setState(catId: item.id)} />
```

But the `onClick` doesn't seem to get fired.

```
export default class extends Component {
  state = {
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.handleChange(this.state);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
     if (this.state !== prevState) {
        this.props.handleChange(this.state);
     }
  }

  render() {
    const { categoriesWithSub } = this.props.categoriesWithSub;
    return (
        {categoriesWithSub &&
          categoriesWithSub.map(item => (
            <Tile
              to="./request"
              department={item.catName}
              key={item.id}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export function Tile({ to, department, onClick }) {
  return (
    <NavLink to={to} css={tile} onClick={onClick}>
      {department}
    </NavLink>
  );
}
```

Comment: `onClick` on a `NavLink` component should work. Did you take the `onClick` prop in the `Tile` component and add it to the `NavLink`?

Comment: the way you are defining onClick is partially correct, onClick will become the part of props object. You need to use it on NavLink in Tile component.

Comment: @Tholle Yes, I do, but it doesn't reach the `componentDidUpdate` method so it doesn't look like it set the state `onClick`

Comment: @user3378165 Alright. I'm not quite sure what you mean by `componentDidMount` in this case, since that will only be invoked when the component is first created. You might want a separate click handler method for that.

Comment: @Tholle Sorry, I meant `componentDidUpdate`. If the state changes it should invoke the `componentDidUpdate` method, isn't it?

Comment: @user3378165 Yes, but `(this.state !== prevState)` might not work as you expect. It's better if you check each property in the state individually instead, or use something like Lodash [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  **Navlink** need the **onClick** that is been passed from your custom component **Tile**

change the export function to

```
export function Tile({ to, department, onClick }) {
  return (
    <NavLink to={to} css={tile} onClick={onClick}>
      {department}
    </NavLink>
  );
}
```

Comment: if it helped don't forget to mark it as the answer. cheers